# Use column names as values in pandas depending on whether value is true or false

Tags: pandas

I have a df thats look like this

```
   500  600  700  800
0   Tr  Fls  Fls  Fls
1   Tr  Tr   Tr   Fls
2 ...
```

And I want to turn it into this

```
   Value
0  500
1  500
1  600
1  700
2 ....
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'500': {0: 'Tr', 1: 'Tr'},
        '600': {0: 'Fls', 1: 'Tr'},
        '700': {0: 'Fls', 1: 'Tr'},
        '800': {0: 'Fls', 1: 'Fls'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

output(`df`):

```
    500 600 700 800
0   Tr  Fls Fls Fls
1   Tr  Tr  Tr  Fls
```

**Code**

When `df` value is 'Tr':

```
df[df=='Tr'].stack().reset_index(level=1)['level_1'].to_frame('Value')
```

result:

```
    Value
0   500
1   500
1   600
1   700
```